# Upload Image to Amazon S3 bucket, .NETCore2

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to upload an Image to S3 bucket. Is it an HTTP Request? or Do I have to use AWS toolkit and SDK or something else. The documentation seem to be very tidy/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this quite easily using the existing SDKs

[AWS and .Net Core 2.0](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/aws-and-net-core-2-0/)

> .NET Core 2.0 supports .NET Standard 2.0 which means any NuGet packages that target .NET Standard 2.0 and below are supported on .NET Core 2.0. The AWS SDK for .NET targets .NET Standard 1.3 which means you can use it for either .NET Core 1.x or .NET Core 2.0.

You can import the `AWSSDK.S3` nuget package which contains the libraries for interacting with an S3 Bucket.

Example:

```
    // if you happened to store this in your appsettings.json
    var accessKey = _configuration["AwsAccessKey"];
    var secretKey = _configuration["AwsSecretKey"];

    var client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

    var request = new PutObjectRequest
    {
        BucketName = "BucketName",
        Key = "KeyName",
        FilePath = "FilePath"
    };

    var response = client.PutObjectAsync(request).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

For further details and examples, please see [Upload an Object Using the AWS SDK for .NET](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpNET.html)

**Update - modified to show example of passing in AccessKey and SecretKey while creating the client**

Comment: How do we Give in the Access Keys and security key. Does it take automatically from AppSetting.Json

Comment: One way would be to read from appsettings.json. You can simply pass this through into the constructor of the `AmazonS3Client`. I've updated the answer to show an example. There are also a number of other ways to authenticate if that doesn't suit your needs, see [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v2/developer-guide/net-dg-config-creds.html)

Comment: My doubt is, If I save it in a profiles file and gice the profile location in appSettings, does ithe SDK read it automatically when a client is created?

Comment: You may need the extension package (`AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCore.Setup`) for this to work, but in theory, it should read it similar to how it is read in app.config/web.config prior to .Net Core. See [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-netcore.html)

Comment: plz take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46599216/aamzons3-image-save-from-base64-netcore2)